# How to go into third person minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've already tried everything YouTube and Google says to do but it doesn't do anything. Is my laptop the problem or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>F5</kbd>, or on some laptops, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> is how you change your perspective between first and third person in Minecraft.

---

On some keyboards, for example, my *Surface Book*, my <kbd>F5</kbd> key both decreases the volume and well, F5.

Depending on the keyboard, <kbd>Fn</kbd> makes the keypress do the sub or main function. You may have to experiment with your keyboard, but that key usually means "do the other thing that's also on that key".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UPHr.jpg]

Comment: I think you should add a sentence about third person reverse, "selfie mode". F5 toggles between the three perspectives.